# EDA- Removing NA's from a column

Tags: r, statistics, analysis

I want to know if i can remove the entire column if it contains over 65% of NA's? If yes Why? and If not, why and how can we deal with NA's in this case?

Thanks

Comment: @akrun provided the technical R answer for how to eliminate columns from a data frame where the percentage of NA values exceeds a threshold. The bigger question about why would I remove a column / how do I deal with the missing values in my data analysis is addressed in [Problems with Missing Values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208845/problems-with-missing-values) on the CrossValidated StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Filter` to remove columns that have greater than 65% of values as NAs

```
Filter(function(x) mean(is.na(x)) <= 0.65, df)
```

---

or with `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select_if(funs(mean(is.na(.)) <= 0.65))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1:5, rep(NA, 5)), V2 = c(1:3, rep(NA, 7)), V3 = c(1:4, rep(NA, 6)))
```